# Sum with list as its upper limit

Tags: list-manipulation

Say I want to create the list
$\{ \sum_{j=1}^{5} 2j, \sum_{j=1}^{6} \frac{5j}{2} \}$
I guessed that this can be done using the code
`Sum[j/{1, 2}*{2, 5}, {j, 1, {5, 6}}]`
However what mathematica gives is
$\Big{\{} \{ \sum_{j=1}^{5} 2j, \sum_{j=1}^{5} \frac{5j}{2} \}, \{ \sum_{j=1}^{6} 2j, \sum_{j=1}^{6} \frac{5j}{2} \} \Big{\}}$
I guess I could just somehow pick out the right element of the result, but is there a more efficient way to achieve this?

EDIT: Eventually I want to apply this to a case, where I have something like
`Sum[f[list,j],{j,1,list}]`

Comment: Maybe: `MapThread[Sum[# j, {j, 1, #2}] &, {{2, 5/2}, {5, 6}}]`

Comment: How can I apply this to an arbitrary list and an arbitrary function of that list, e.g. something like `Sum[f[list,j],{j,1,list}]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very well-defined. It *seems* that you have a list of different functions, f1, f2, f3, etc., and you want to sum each of those functions to different maximum values. Is that correct? If so:

```
f1[j_]=2j;
f2[j_]=5j/2;
funclist={f1,f2};
maxsumlist={5,6};
result=MapThread[Sum[#1@j,{j,1,#2}]&,{funclist,maxsumlist}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps

```
sum[a_, b_, c_] := Sum[a j, {j, b, c}]
SetAttributes[sum, Listable]
```

Examples:

```
sum[{2, 5}/{1, 2}, 1, {5, 6}]
```

> {30, 105/2}

```
sum[{a, b}, 1, {n, m}]
```

> {1/2 a n (1 + n), 1/2 b m (1 + m)}

```
sum[{foo[j], bar[j]}, q, {n, m}] // TeXForm
```

> $\left\{\sum _{j=q}^n j \text{foo}(j),\sum _{j=q}^m j \text{bar}(j)\right\}$